# I can't figure out how to update my jQuery code to plain JS and utilize the Fetch method for my Movie Search app using API for data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I developed a basic site using CSS, semantic HTML, JavaScript, and API. I have built a basic search application using HTML, sass(scss), gulp, and JavaScript. It connects to an API that populates a page with the results. I chose to utilize the Movie Database API. However, I used jQuery and now need to convert it with just plain JS and the Fetch method. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <title>Movie Box</title>
</head>

<body>
    
<!-----*** HEADER ***----->    
<header>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <nav>
            <!-- LOGO -->
            <h1>MovieBox Logo</h1>
            <!-- NAV LINKS -->
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- SEARCH FORM -->
    <form action="#" class="js-search-form">
        <p class="form-p">Search for movies by Title</p>

        <div class="search">
        <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
        <input type="text" class="js-query" placeholder="ex. Star Wars" autofocus>
        </div>
        
        <button id="ghost-btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</header>
    
<!-----*** SECTION - SEARCH RESULTS ***-----> 
<section class="js-search-results clearfix">
 
</section>

<!-----*** SECTION - VIEW MORE ***----->
<section>
        <p class="max center-text">Showing max result of 20</p>
        <p class="center-text">
        <a class="btn second-btn" href="https://www.imdb.com/find" target="_blank">View More Details on IMDB</a>
        </p>
</section>

<!-----*** FOOTER ***----->
<footer>Built by Eileen Villahermosa for DWS2</footer>  
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Here is my JS:

```
// Single state variable for endpoint
var MD_BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?

include_adult=false&page=1";

var state = {
    query: ''
};

// State modification functions

function getApiData(searchTerm, callback) {
    var query = {
        query: searchTerm,
        language: 'en-US',
        api_key: 'sssssssssssssss', // took the key out for privacy
    };
    $.getJSON(MD_BASE_URL, query, callback);
}

// Render functions
function displayMDSearchData(data) {
    
    var resultElement = '';
    
    if(data.results.length > 1) {
        resultElement += '<section class="js-search-results clearfix">';
resultElement += '<h2>' + '<span>' + "Results for " + state.query + '</span>' + '</h2>';

if(data.results)

data.results.forEach(function(results){
    resultElement += '<article>';
    resultElement += '<div class="container">';
    resultElement += '<img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + results.poster_path + '"/>';
    resultElement += '<div class="content">';
    if(results.title.length > 20) {
       resultElement += '<h3>' + results.title.substr(0,20) +'...</h3>'; 
    } else {
        resultElement += '<h3>' + results.title + '</h3>';             
      }
     
    resultElement += '<p>Released: ' + results.release_date + '</p>';
    resultElement += '</div>';
    resultElement += '</div>';
    resultElement += '</article>';
});

resultElement += '</section>';
console.log(data);
   

     
    } else {
        resultElement += '<p class="no-results">No results</p>';
    }
    
    $('.js-search-results').html(resultElement);
}

// Event listeners
function watchSubmit() {
  $('.js-search-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    state.query = $(this).find('.js-query').val();
    var query = state.query;
    getApiData(query, displayMDSearchData);
    });
  }

$(function(){watchSubmit();});
```

Comment: It looks like you want to try changing `$.getJSON(MD_BASE_URL, query, callback)` to `fetch(MD_BASE_URL + "?query=" + searchTerm + "&language=en-US" + "&api_key= sssssssssssssss").then(response => response.json()).then(data => displayMDSearchData(data))`. But if you try that and find it doesn’t work, then use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52177424/edit to edit/update the question to say that’s what you’ve tried so far — and to say what errors you ran into with that.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks so much! I will try this, and if it does't work I will update my questions! Truly appreciate it!